# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when use getFragmentManager() with actionbarsherlock library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My own project uses:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

To implement **action bar**, I uses [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library. I imported the **sherlock** library into my Eclipse as an existing project. For **sherlock**, the target platform is **Android v3.2 API 13** .

Then, I added **sherlock** as a library project to my own project. I saw there is Library projects under my own project. Everything seem goes well.

My own project main Activity looks like this:

```
package com.test;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * hosts a Fragment, and the Fragment will inflate a layout to show
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fragMgr;
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans;

        fragMgr = getFragmentManager(); //error complains here


           FirstFragment list = new FirstFragment();

        fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
        fragTrans.add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();

    }
}
```

But, when I run my application, I got the following **error**:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.test.MyActivity.getFragmentManager
```

Why `getFragment` can not be resolved as a method?? I have used sherlock as a project library for my own project...

Answer (score 31):

The method `getFragmentManager()` is available only since 3.0, in the `Activity` class. Since your target sdk is 13, and `FragmentActivity` extends from `Activity` there are no problems at compilation time.

But when you run your code on a lower sdk (7 for example) there is no such method in that `Activity` class. So the solution is to use :

```
 getSupportFragmentManager();
```

which will work on all `Android` versions.

Comment: How to call getSupportFragmentManager() outside of FragmentActivity? ie. In a ViewGroup implementation.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use

> FragmentTransaction transaction =
>   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

and make sure you are importing:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: To make sure your project is setup correctly I created a screen cast located at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k which is now part of the FAQ at ABS's site. It does not cover what you are asking but it will ensure the rest of the project is setup correctly.

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.ActionBar; not working, work arounds?