# "No such method error" when using getfragmentmanager() in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

In my application I am using Dialog fragment as splash screen.So it will show the splash screen on app startup. When I run the app on devices below android version 3 , it shows an error like "`No such method error:getFragmentManager`".I have seen that it can be solved by using `getSupportFragmentManager()`.But When I use it,Splash dialog is not showing.Please some one help me..Thanks in advance...

Main Activity=>

```
        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //Here I am using getFragmentManager
    newFragment = SplashDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(MainActivity.ft, "dialog");
```

And here is my Splash Screen Fragment=>

```
public class SplashDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText mEditText;


    static SplashDialogFragment newInstance() {
        SplashDialogFragment f = new SplashDialogFragment();
        return f;
    }
    public void EditNameDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme);        
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash_fragment, container);


        return view;
    }

    public void show(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }


}
```

And erro log=>

```
 > 12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.myapp.mlm.MainActivity.getFragmentManager
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.madhyamam.malayalam2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    12-07 11:09:09.330: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by extending my MainActivity to FragmentActivity. Previously it was extending Activity.After that I have used getSupportFragmentManager without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

android.support.v4.app.Fragment; because Fragment is available in API level 11.
please see this link:- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html

and this link :-

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when use getFragmentManager() with actionbarsherlock library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196400/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-when-use-getfragmentmanager-with-actionbarsherlock)

put support jar file in libs add in build path folder and import like android.support.v4.app.Fragment,instead of previous.
         Hope this will be help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that it will fail on version lower that 3. Please have look at 
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html
You might try using compatibility jar.

This might help you
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/